# Python Dataframe perfom algebric operation between different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, lambda

I have a data frame of three columns. I want to check them if they follow a logical sequence.

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'low':[10,15,np.nan]','medium:[12,18,29],'high':[16,19,np.nan]})
df = 
    low     medium  high
0   10.0    12      16.0
1   15.0    18      19.0
2   NaN     29      NaN

# check if low<medium<high
df['check'] = (df['low']<df['medium'])&(df['medium']<df['high'])
print("Condition failed: %s"%(df['check'].all()))
```

Present output:

```
df['check']=
True #correct
True # correct
False # wrong output here, it should not consider this
```

Basically I want to avoid comparison with the NaN values and producing false output. I want to avoid them. How can I do it?

Comment: `df2 = df.dropna()` then 
`(df2["low"] < df2["medium"]) < df2["high"]` This can also get you the desired output .

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Thought about it but I don't want to drop them.

Comment: Then what you want in case of nan items ? It should give false in case of blanks if not dropped ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `mask` it. Also, instead of chained condition, you can use `between`:

```py
df['check'] = df['medium'].between(df['low'], df['high'], inclusive='neither').mask(df[['low','high']].isna().any(axis=1))
```

Output:

```py
    low  medium  high check
0  10.0      12  16.0  True
1  15.0      18  19.0  True
2   NaN      29   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: How to do make net comparison? I mean will `df['check'].all()` produce a True? or False?

Comment: @Mainland you can do: `df['check'].dropna().all()`

Comment: @Mainland but if the goal is not to append a new column but the total, then maybe skip `mask` and filter instead: `df['medium'].between(df['low'], df['high'], inclusive='neither')[df[['low','high']].notna().all(axis=1)].all()`